# Attempts to replace an element of an array with an element of another array result in appending that element at the end of the array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have two arrays of the same length, the first one with all zeros, the second one with non-zero values:

```
az0=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
az=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate over array `az`, copying array `az0` to array `spaz`, replacing the i-th element of array `spaz` with the i-th element of array `az`, repeating this each iteration so I can get:

```
spaz=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
spaz=(0 45 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
spaz=(0 0 315 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
…
spaz=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 180)
```

I do this in a loop ('debug' mode):

```
for((i=0;i<${#az[@]};i++))
do
    spaz=${az0[@]}
    echo '${spaz[*]}=('`echo ${spaz[*]}`')'
    echo '${az[*]}=('`echo ${az[*]}`')'
    az=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
    echo "i=$i"
    echo '${az'[$i]'}='`echo ${az[$i]}`
    spaz[$i]=${az[$i]}
    echo '${spaz'[$i]'}'=`echo ${spaz[$i]}`
    echo '${spaz[*]}=('`echo ${spaz[*]}`')'
    echo
    unset spaz
    read -rsp $'Press any key to continue or q or CTRL-C to quit...\n' -n 1 key
    if [[ "$key" = "q" ]] then echo; exit; fi
    echo
done
```

Run mode:

```
for((i=0;i<${#az[@]};i++))
do
    spaz=${az0[@]}
    az=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
    spaz[$i]=${az[$i]}
    unset spaz
done
```

The problem is that, although the i-th element of array `spaz` seems to be getting replaced, when I echo the altered array, the i-th element is appended to the array:

```
${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
${az[*]}=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
i=0
${az[0]}=0
${spaz[0]}=0
${spaz[*]}=(0)

${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
${az[*]}=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
i=1
${az[1]}=45
${spaz[1]}=45
${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 45)

${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
${az[*]}=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
i=2
${az[2]}=315
${spaz[2]}=315
${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 315)

…

${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
${az[*]}=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)
i=9
${az[9]}=180
${spaz[9]}=180
${spaz[*]}=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 180)
```

I find it somewhat disturbing that for i=0, ${spaz[*]}=(0) instead of (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0). This may indicate the problem but I don't know why. There must be a reason for this. It's probably some small thing that I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a language tag for more visibility - looks like BASH (but not quite).

Comment: add some clarity on what you are trying to achieve it doesnt make sense when you say you are copying an array when you are only copying an element of an array.  further what is your end goal?

Comment: Replace `spaz=${az0[@]}` with `spaz=(${az0[@]})` which produces desired result.   For example on 2nd iteration the last output is : `${spaz[*]}=(0 45 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)`

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was missing. This is the only useful answer. All others are hypercritical or irrelevant, and unhelpful to the clearly stated problem IMO.

Comment: As for the downvote and UpAndAdam's comment, that I was "copying an array when you are only copying an element of an array",  and to which 5f3bde39-70a2-4df1-afa2-47f61b graciously pointed out the simple solution of adding parentheses, I spent a lot of time writing my question very carefully, giving exact code, all details and outputs, and specifying exactly what my goal was. No further explanation is necessary IMO. I obviously have a reason for asking the question. People don't ask questions about things that they already know.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the code (assigning an array to a string).  The report includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

az0=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
az=(0 45 315 90 270 120 240 150 210 180)

for((i=0;i<${#az[@]};i++))
do
    for((j=0;j<${#az0[@]};j++))
    do
       spaz[j]=${az0[j]}
    done
    spaz[i]=${az[i]}
    declare -p spaz
done
```

---

```
$ bash test.sh
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="45" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="315" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="90" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="270" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="120" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="240" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="150" [8]="0" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="210" [9]="0")
declare -a spaz=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="0" [3]="0" [4]="0" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="0" [8]="0" [9]="180")
```